# Databinding function to a Label which is an ItemTemplate of a datalist and calculates total price in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a small shopping cart website in asp.net and c#. My problem is in the checkout page I want to display the total price of each product by calculating adding tax to price. I have a datalist which has an ItemTemplate as label for total where I want to bind function call CalculateTotal(price, tax). In database, price has Varchar(MAX) and tax has float datatype. When I tried I got below error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'ProgearHire.Hire.CalculateTotal(string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Source Error:

Line 232:        
Line 233:            
Line 234:            ' runat="server" />
Line 235:        
Line 236:

The code which I used is below:

```
        <td align="center">
        <asp:Label ID="lbTotal" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label Visible="false" ID="Label9" Value='<%#(CalculateTotal(Eval("Price"), Eval("Tax"))) %>' runat="server" />
    </td>
```

Function:

```
  public float CalculateTotal(string x, string y)
    {
        p = Convert.ToInt32(x);
        q = Convert.ToInt32(y);
        return (float)p * (float)q;
    }
```

Can anybody help me in find out the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mshsayem I have tried but its giving the following error "<asp:Label Visible="false" ID="Label9" Value='<%#(CalculateTotal((string)Eval("OneDayPrice"), (string)Eval("Tax"))) %>' runat="server" />"

Comment: @mshsayem Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.

Answer (score 1):

dear friend your code is doing well but the lable control have no value property your have to make your lable to text property so make your code like the bellow

```
     <td align="center">
    <asp:Label ID="lbTotal" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label Visible="false" ID="Label9" Text='<%#(CalculateTotal(Eval("Price"), Eval("Tax"))) %>' runat="server" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `CalculateTotal(string x, string y)` is expecting two `string` arguments, but you are supplying `object`s as the `Eval()` method returns `object`. Correct as follows:

```
... Value='<%# CalculateTotal(Eval("Price") as string, Eval("Tax") as string) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest casting each parameter to a string, Eval returns object. As below:

```
<asp:Label Visible="false" ID="Label9" Value='<%#(CalculateTotal((string)Eval("Price"), (string)Eval("Tax"))) %>' runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given wrong attribute for label. It would be "Text" instead of "Value"

```
<asp:Label Visible="false" ID="Label9" Value='<%#(CalculateTotal(Eval("Price"), Eval("Tax"))) %>' runat="server" />
```

Replace with this

```
<asp:Label Visible="false" ID="Label9" Text='<%# CalculateTotal(Convert.ToString(Eval("Price")), Convert.ToString(Eval("Tax"))) %>' runat="server" />
```

Your error will solve. Also, in the Calculate function you have convert the string to int and return as float. This is also wrong as the tax might be in a decimal format. Please do check that thing

Change your function as below.

```
public Double CalculateTotal(string x, string y)
        {
            Double p = Convert.ToDouble(x);
            Double q = Convert.ToDouble(y);
            return (p * q);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The code looks great..

```
<asp:Label Visible="false" ID="Label9" Text='<%# CalculateTotal(Convert.ToString(Eval("Price")), Convert.ToString(Eval("Tax"))) %>' runat="server" />
```

Try the function like this..

```
public Double CalculateTotal(object x, object y)
        {
            Double p = Convert.ToDouble(x);
            Double q = Convert.ToDouble(y);
            return (p * q);
        }
```

It is working for me. Happy coding.